# Android Interface -- Restrict TextViews to a Scrollbox

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, textview

I'm using a relative layout with three TextViews, one on top of each other. Then, relative to the bottom of the screen, there is a compass like setup of four buttons, and relative to that top one, there are three buttons above it, an EditText and another Button are atop that.

[image]

I want the three TextViews to be stacked atop one another still, but I want them to be in a scroll-box that extends from the top of the interface, to the top of the EditText. However, I have no idea how to do this in XML for Android. Does anyone have any suggestions, or links to helpful tutorials on the matter?

Edit: My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Turn S" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnS"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/turnS"
        android:text="Turn W" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnS"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/turnS"
        android:text="Turn E" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnW"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Turn N" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lookB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnN"
        android:text="     Look     " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnN"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="     Take    " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/useB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnN"
        android:text="       Use     " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/useB"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edittext" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lookView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#FFA500"

        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/lookView"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/hello" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/lookB"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Enter" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot,
Zeldarulah

Comment: not clear, can you please tell me what you mean by this "I want the three TextViews to be stacked atop one another still, but I want them to be in a scroll-box that extends from the top of the interface"

Comment: I want all of the buttons and the input on the bottom to remain where they are, but I want the overflowing text to stop above the edit box, and then, so that it can be seen, you can scroll up and down it to see all of it.

Comment: post your xml file here, thanks

Comment: Sure, I added it to the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Turn S" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnS"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/turnS"
        android:text="Turn W" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnS"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/turnS"
        android:text="Turn E" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnW"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Turn N" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lookB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnN"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="     Look     " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnN"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="     Take    " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/useB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/turnN"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="       Use     " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/useB"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edittext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/lookB"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Enter" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/edittext" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lookView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:textColor="#FFA500" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:textColor="#FFFF00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:text="@string/hello"
                android:textColor="#00FF00" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've been working on this at school, and as such I won't have an opportunity to test it until Monday, but, this ScrollView + LinearLayout combination was exactly what I thought had to be done, so I'm expecting it to work. (I found out about ScrollView on friday, and learned it had to be used with a Linear, but then ran out of time.)

Thanks a ton, I'll try that out as soon as I can. :)

Comment: @Zeldarulah You could use any `View` instead of the `LinearLayout` it's just that `ScrollView` requires that it must have only one child.

Comment: @Zeldarulah I don't understand what are you trying to do, maybe a picture(or a better description)?

Comment: Nevermind, I changed some stuff around so it now works better to have it default on the top anyway. Thanks for all the help.